# Geometry question- is x degrees within plus or minus y degrees of z

Tags: geometry

This is not at all what I do so please keep it simple.
I'm looking for a true/false condition for a php program I'm working on.

The best way for me to describe the question is by example.

> I'm given $2$ directions and $2$ angles like
>
> $A=181$ with possible values $0$ to $360$
> $B=160$
> $x=5$ with possible values $0$ to $180$
> $y=10$

What I'm looking for is $A+x \ge B \ge A-y  $
which obvious doesn't work.

I'm developing a relationship between wind direction and crosswind conditions for aircraft and this just has me stumpted.

Thanks for the help...

***Real world example*** Runway 350 DFW, my aircraft can handle 20 degrees cross wind from strait. The morning of my flight the briefer indicates winds at 050.True or false can I launch my aircraft?

Comment: Is A a vector or a number? What then does 181 mean?  Same for B, x and y...How do you define "direction" in your question?

Comment: They are numbers, compass directions North=360 etc. x, y I call sweep left and right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I'm looking for is $A+x≥B≥A−y$ which obvious doesn't work.

Why not? If the only thing that bothers you is the wraparound, you can write something like this:

```
d = B - (A - y)
while (d < 0) d += 360
while (d >= 360) d -= 360
reutrn d ≤ x + y
```

The first line computes the difference between the actual direction and the second limit direction. By normalizing that angle to the range $[0,360)$, the second inequality will hold automatially, as the angle is $\geq0$. Then you can check the first inequality to see whether your direction lies within the allowed sector.

Comment: It was the wraparound causing the problem. Your absolutely correct. Sincerely appreciated Thank you!