# How to check whether a direction is within in a sector?

Tags: geometry

I'm doing work with wind direction data, and will be coding a function that checks whether the a given wind direction is bewteen lower and upper limit or bound

e.g.:

1. Is 5 degrees is between 315 degrees and 45 degrees? True
2. Is 310 degrees between 315 degrees and 45 degrees? False
3. Is 180 degrees between 45 degrees and 315 degrees? True

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281172/geometry-question-is-x-degrees-within-plus-or-minus-y-degrees-of-z) to another question is close, in that it has a great way to deal with the wraparound, but I can't quite see how to adapt it for my situation.

Comment: Your link is broken.

Comment: Is it possible to code it such that, if lower bound > upper bound (numerically), break the interval into 2 and compare? e.g. example 1,2 becomes checking for the ranges $315^\circ-360^\circ$ and $0^\circ-45^\circ$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is $\beta$ between $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ ?

First, what you decide when $\beta=\alpha$ or $\beta=\gamma$ is perhaps up to interpretation and you should check for that case first.

If $\alpha<\beta<\gamma$ or $\beta<\gamma<\alpha$ or $\gamma<\alpha<\beta$ (i.e., they are in cyclic order), then: Yes. Otherwise: No

Comment: Bang on, Thank you so much! The idea of cyclic order is fanastic. I've built a table to test it and it all works. Three cheers for the math community!

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand, your bounds are $\alpha$ and $\beta$ where either of them can be bigger like in your first case $\alpha = 315^0, \beta = 45^0$ whereas in the third case, it is $\alpha = 45^0, \beta = 315^0$.

Say, you need to check for an angle $\gamma$.

i) If $\alpha \lt \beta$, then if $\alpha \le \gamma \le \beta$, then it is indeed between them (TRUE). Otherwise false.

ii) If $\alpha \gt \beta$, then if $\beta \lt \gamma \lt \alpha$,  then consider it is NOT between them (FALSE). Otherwise True.

Take your third case and apply in (i) as $\alpha (45^0) \lt \beta (315^0)$. As $\gamma = 180^0$, it will return TRUE.

Take your second case and apply in (ii) as $\alpha (315^0) \gt \beta (45^0)$. As $\gamma = 310^0$, gamma is more than $\beta$ and less than $\alpha$, it will return FALSE.

Similarly your first case will return true as the value of $\gamma (5^0)$ is outside $(\beta, \alpha)$.